# How do I sort the "/etc/passwd" UIDs?

Tags: sync, script, automation, awk, etcpasswd

I have been banging my head on this little project the past few days and here is how it goes...

I need to organize all the UIDs for multiple servers so all users have the same UID 
in their `/etc/passwd`. Obviously I am trying to find a proper script for this so I do not have to do this manually.

If I have 1 correct server with the correct UIDs could someone recommend a manageable script to sync other servers /etc/passwd with the correct one?

I got as far as orgizing it with using

```
awk -F ':' '{print$1,$3}' /etc/passwd
```

Then I can use `diff` or `sort` to compare the updated `passwd` file with the old `passwd` file.

Comment: please post samples with an exemple of what you want before and after (you can conceal sensible parts)

Comment: For an actual solution, stop keeping network-wide accounts in `/etc/passwd`. There are NIS and LDAP for that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. 
I here is what I would like to have       
Server 1 (incorrect UIDs)                                                               /etc/passwd                                                                
jspasser:x:509   
mrayes:x:507                                                                
ssmith:x:501 
ljackson:x503                                                         

Server 2   (correct UIDs)
jspasser:x:1001
mrayes:x:1001
ssmith:x:1002
ljackson:x:1003

Comment: @ grawity... good point, someone else brought that up in the past but its kinda out of our hands to make that decision:( . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grawity has the right idea in his comment...if it had to be a script, it would need to be pretty complicated to work without a reboot...as in change all uids to something crazy high then to the right base number with usermod

it would be way easier in python...and i think that's included in most linux distros as standard now.  if you need a python script that does the work, say so.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess, shlex


newlistolists = []
with open('/root/masterpasswd', 'r') as newetcpass:
    for line in newetcpass:
        alist = line.split(':')
        newlistolists.append(alist[:])

for entry in newlistolists:
    cmd = 'usermod -o -u ' + entry[2] + ' ' + entry[0]
    thecmd = shlex.split(cmd)
    subprocess.Popen(thecmd)

#insert additional logic for setting groups, shells, etc with relevant commands
#you need to do some error handling too, but it's a fast ugly UID set script
```

Only include usernames you want to change in /root/masterpasswd

Comment: I would be most appreciated if you could supply a python script to make this work. I am trying to do this for myself now but I am not sure if its being done correctly. thanks in advance

Comment: Works in my testing...you still need to worry about groups etc

Comment: thank you soo much for this.  This helped me quite a bit! consider this thread resolved